# How can I get the bottom result?

Tags: java

This the recursion that I did so far, but it doesn't  seem to be correct, this is mainly out of interest. Any help or hint will be appreciated.

```
public class CompareStrings { 
    public static boolean match(String x, String y) {
        //turn each string into a char[], sort that array,
        //then compare the two Simple 
        char[] first  = x.toCharArray();
        char[] second = y.toCharArray();
        java.util.Arrays.sort(first);
        java.util.Arrays.sort(second);
        String sorted_str1 = new String(x);
        String sorted_str2 = new String(y);

        if(sorted_str1.equals(sorted_str2)){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    } 

    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        System.out.println(match("hello", "hello.")); // should return false
        System.out.println(match("hello", "jello")); // should return false
        System.out.println(match("hello", "h@llo")); // should return true
        System.out.println(match("hello", "h@@@@")); // should return true
        System.out.println(match("hello", "h*")); // should return true
        System.out.println(match("hello", "*l*")); // should return true
        System.out.println(match("anyString", "*")); // should return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you using recursion ?

Comment: Usually, instead of 3 you write 1+1+1. This makes your expression more readable. Therefore, when you write `if(x) return true else return false` instead of `return x`, you make a right choice. However, there is even a more readable form: write `if(x) {if (true) return true else return false} else {if (true) return false else return true}` instead. 1+1+1-1+1 is more readable than 1+1+1.

Comment: @Val http://www.uibk.ac.at/econometrics/lit/siegfried_jpe_70.pdf

Comment: ok, I am just confused I thought I was using recursion

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how sorting and chars in the strings the calling `equals` magically makes wildcards work.

Comment: @mvitagames you are using String#equals() to compare two strings so contents of each string should be equal in order to return true. For all your test case it will print false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remember that if you want to use *Recursion* you must use your function inside of itself. Look and example:

```
void myMethod( int counter)
{
if(counter == 0)
else
{
System.out.println("hello" + counter);
myMethod(--counter);
System.out.println(""+counter);
}
}
```

My function is myMethod and I'm using it inside of itself. But you're not doing it, so you\re not using *Recursion*.

Comment: oc ic that actually makes sense

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about recursion, but why not just do something as simple as

```
public static boolean match(String x, String y) {
    return x.matches(y.replace("@", ".").replace("*", ".*"));
}
```

In regex-land,

- `.` matches any character
- `X*` matches `X` *0 or more times*
- Consequently, `.*` matches any string, including an empty string

Judging by your examples, you want `@` to match a single character and `*` to match any string. So, we replace all `@`s in `y` with `.` and replace all `*`s with `.*`, and use the resulting string as a regular expression, checking if `x` matches it.

---

```
System.out.println(match("hello", "hello."));
System.out.println(match("hello", "jello"));
System.out.println(match("hello", "h@llo"));
System.out.println(match("hello", "h@@@@"));
System.out.println(match("hello", "h*"));
System.out.println(match("hello", "*l*"));
System.out.println(match("anyString", "*"));
```

```
false
false
true
true
true
true
true
```